Can't install rocksdict on Raspberry Pi 4 server (buster aarch64)
I had installed Python 3.9.1 for a specific user and tried to install rocksdict in a virtual environment. However, I am getting the following error message:
$ python3 -m pip install rocksdict
    Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement rocksdict (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for rocksdict

I also tried to install rocksdict___.whl, but this produced the same error message.
Is it possible to install rocksdict, or is there no version for Raspberry Pi buster?

Indeed, the documentation only mentions amd64 and arm64 for Linux.

I need rocksdict only for installation of quixstreams (Kafka testing)
